# Differentiating between different running instances of a process

Tags: c#

I was wondering how to differentiate between two different instances of a software that is running in C#. Let's say I have 2 different videos running with the same software (both with KMPlayer) or I have two remote desktop sessions (mstsc.exe) open at the same time. I can use this code to get all the instances :

```
Process.GetProcessesByName("mstsc");
```

But how can I differentiate between those instances?
I am mainly looking to differentiate the different running video instances and remote desktop instances in my software.

Comment: What would be the differentiating characteristic?

Comment: Let say for remote desktop the ip address or name of the server that it is connected to and for the video, the name of the video file.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Server Name and Process ID?"

Comment: Do you know what values you are looking for or they could be anything? I mean, will you be trying to find the `mstsc` process that's connected to "SERVER1" and the one that's connected to "SERVER2". Or you won't know the name of either one?

Comment: I know the name of the servers for each remote desktop, for example 1 remote desktop is connected to server1.domain.com and second one is connected to server2.domain.com, and for the videos, one video is for example video1.avi and second video is video2.avi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if Process Id or MainWindowTitle works for you.